# Couldn't resolve host 'git-wip-us.apache.org' while accessing https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/thrift.git/info/refs

Tags: git, thrift, git-clone

I am running Cloudera (Linux) and need to clone a server for thrift installation. The command I used is
Couldn't resolve host 'git-wip-us.apache.org' while accessing https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/thrift.git/info/refs

However I am getting the following error :
Couldn't resolve host 'git-wip-us.apache.org' while accessing https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/thrift.git/info/refs

Please help.

Comment: What does `nslookup git-wip-us.apache.org` give you? Because it doesn't resolve for me.

Comment: "*The command I used is Couldn't resolve host 'git-wip-us.apache.org' while accessing https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/thrift.git/info/refs*"  --  That command seems wrong. Typo?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is outdated.

Answer (score 1):

### Update

The repo has been moved to Github a while ago. That makes the question kind of obsolete, nevertheless the Apache Thrift web site may still be considered to get the right URL.

---

As http://thrift.apache.org/developers tells us, the following should work:

```
git clone https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/thrift.git
```

And it does:

```
$ git clone https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/thrift.git
Cloning into 'thrift'...
remote: Counting objects: 51016, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (12715/12715), done.
remote: Total 51016 (delta 37329), reused 48290 (delta 34735)
Receiving objects: 100% (51016/51016), 10.59 MiB | 1.97 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (37329/37329), done.
```